# Access Run time error - '-2147352567

Tags: ms-access, vba

error occurred from "clear Button" there are two field with data type with date& time

```
Private Sub cmdClear_Click()

    Me.SampleCode = ""
    Me.ReceivedDate = ""
    Me.SampleQuntity = ""
    Me.SampleReceivedTime = ""
    Me.SampleName = ""
    Me.BatchNo = ""
    Me.MRANo = ""
    Me.Division = ""
    Me.SubmittedBy = ""
    Me.ReceivedBy = ""
    Me.AssignedTo = ""

    ''focuse on SampleCode txtBox
    Me.SampleCode.SetFocus

End Sub
```

Comment: Code cannot be VBA and VB.NET. Please read the description of a tag before adding it.  The description of the VB.NET tag SPECIFICALLY states that it should not be used for VBA questions.

Comment: I am not familiar with VB but Date and Time cannot be empty strings. It must be a method to set them to empty date.

Comment: Thanks for support

Comment: Just tried setting up a database with a table and a form with a button such as yours. Works for me. Can you try to comment out each line of your Clear procedure in turn, to see if it is the date time fields that give the error?

Answer (score 1):

Without any further information to go on it's either:

- Your received date can't accept any empty string.
  If it can't be `Null` then set it to something like `01-01-1900`.
- Any fields that are numeric should be set to `Null` or `0`.
- It could be that you've misspelt `SampleQuntity`. Should it be `SampleQuantity`?